# How can I make font-size for font icons totally responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm developing an Android app using Cordova in which there are multiple font-icons used. I used media queries for different screen sizes to set the font-size for the "body" by percent. I also added queries based on orientation to try and make it responsive for orientation-change. But still the icons look oddly smaller or larger for different screens as there can be tablets as well as mid-sized phones that can have the same resolution. So my question is, is there a better way to make my font-icons responsive regardless of the screen size, DPI, resolution? I'm using Fontello font-icons.

Comment: maybe you should use [Icon-fonts](http://css-tricks.com/examples/IconFont/)

Comment: That's the same as font icons. I'm already using them. I need to make it's size responsive.

Comment: Did you find a solution ?